# How do I fix "This Serverless Function has crashed" on vercel when deploying Sveltekit

Tags: javascript, render, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am new to svelte and do not really understand how the server side code works.
my projects works fine on local server but returns an error when deployed to vercel:
[image: error on web]

I still have a build error trying to deploy with Render too:

[image: error on web]

I currently do not understand  why this error keeps coming up please I need help with this.
this is a link to the github:

https://github.com/Dxtobi/webmart_frontend_web

and the way my files are structured

[image: file structured]

Comment: Can you check your [Vercel serverless function logs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs#function-logs) to see what the actual error is? This will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: @starball
 I also drop a link to the entire project on Github the

Comment: Thanks for the github link, but please also see the instructions in [ask] on how to help others reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok @starball what is it that you do not understand about the question, and how can I make it clearer. I asked the question in the most simplest way I could how else would you prefer because the question did pass the question test before I clicked on the ask question button.

Comment: I gave you some feedback in my first comment, but you still haven't addressed it :)